# My blog isn't centered

Tags: blogger

I've been working on a new blog design for the past few days and I like the way it looks at this moment, but there's a few things wrong. This is the link to my blog: http://aardbeicitroenthee.blogspot.nl/ (it's a test blog)

1. Not everything is centered (if you look closely: the 'older posts' text is more to the right than the 'newer posts' text.) I think it has something to do with my page width but I can't fix it myself.
2. The menu (so the 'about me' tags et cetera) are very small but I can't make them bigger: I can't adjust the font size. How can I fix this?

Thank you so much in advance. Have a nice evening!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the 'older posts' link is at the very right of your wrapper. Adjusting the margins on the '.snips-image' divs should even it out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `font-size` property in the `.menu a` css class will allow you to change the size of the font :

```
.menu a {
    font-size: 50px; /* add this line */
    float: center;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 36px;
    padding: 0 28px;
}
```